# How to check if a function has been called with a truthy value (not f.e. undefined) in Jasmine?

Tags: jasmine

In Jasmine there are functions .toHaveBeenCalledWith() and .toBeTruthy(), but is there a way to check if a function has been called with a value that is truthy?

As far as I know with .toHaveBeenCalledWith() you have to pass an exact value, but I would just like to check if a function has been called with a truthy value (not undefined or null, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is set up a spy on the function you are trying to test the argument of. Then get the argument via the spy, e.g. `let my arg = mySpy.calls.mostRecent().args[0];` and the do a simple expectation `expect(arg).toBeTruthy()`.

Pseudo code snippet:

```
let mySpy = spyOn(myComponent, 'myFunctionToSpyOn').and.callThrough();

// do something that triggers the function call

let arg = mySpy.calls.mostRecent().args[0];
expect(arg).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: Doing it this way I am getting an error : "[ts] Property 'args' does not exist on type '() => CallInfo'.". What could be wrong here?

Comment: It needs to be mostRecent(), my bad. It is a function not a property.